# vue.js webpack how to import fonts from scss file

Tags: webpack, vue.js, sass

I have a package

**package.json**

....
  "themify-icons-scss": "git+https://github.com/erwin16/themify-icons-sass",
  ....

that I import in my App.vue component

**App.vue**

```
<style lang="scss">
@import "~themify-icons-scss/scss/themify-icons.scss";
```

But I get a build error

```
These relative modules were not found:* ../fonts//themify.ttf?-fvbane in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"minimize":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compi
ler?{"optionsId":"0","vue":true,"scoped":false,"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue

* ../fonts/themify.eot in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"minimize":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"opt
ionsId":"0","vue":true,"scoped":false,"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue

* ../fonts/themify.eot?-fvbane in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"minimize":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compil
er?{"optionsId":"0","vue":true,"scoped":false,"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue

* ../fonts/themify.svg?-fvbane in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"minimize":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"optionsId":"0","vue":true,"scoped":false,"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue

* ../fonts/themify.woff?-fvbane in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"minimize":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"optionsId":"0","vue":true,"scoped":false,"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
```

**node_modules/themify-icons-scss/scss/themify-icon.scss**

```
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "path";
@import "core";
@import "extras";
@import "icons";
```

**node_modules/themify-icons-scss/scss/_path.scss**

```
/* FONT PATH
 * -------------------------- */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'themify';
    src:url('#{$ti-font-path}/themify.eot?-fvbane');
    src:url('#{$ti-font-path}/themify.eot?#iefix-fvbane') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('#{$ti-font-path}/themify.woff?-fvbane') format('woff'),
        url('#{$ti-font-path}//themify.ttf?-fvbane') format('truetype'),
        url('#{$ti-font-path}/themify.svg?-fvbane#themify') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

feedback welcome

Comment: file-loader + resolve-url-loader will be useful here. File loader to copy the files for distribution, resolve url loader to use the paths mapped by the file loader

Comment: thanks for feedback..as you mentionned , it's ok to do it using vue-cli v2 ( that's  what I already did ) howver my issue is doing it now with vue-cli version 3-beta ... not easy to find any example...

Comment: thanks for feedback... that's what I did  before when using vue-cli v2 .. however I am testing vue-cli v3-beta .. few examples on how to do it ... the current issue is that src:url('#{$ti-font-path}  variable is defines as $ti-font-path: "../fonts" !default;  and the sass-loader cannot get it ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to call it with a URL import example how I did for the google fonts

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Font-Name";
  src: url("/fonts/font-name.eot");
  src: url("/fonts/font-name.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("/fonts/font-name.woff") format("woff"),
    url("/fonts/font-name.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("/fonts/font-name.svg#font-name") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic");
```